# Is it possible to do a concave and rounded corner of the same element?

Tags: css, progress-bar

I need it to look like this: [image]

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="hni_vaBreadcrumbContainer">
  <progress class="hni_vaBreadcrumbProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <span class="hni_vaBreadcrumbContent">0%</span>
</div>
```

Here are a couple jfiddles I tried but couldn't get working:
http://jsfiddle.net/x4wLf/,  http://jsfiddle.net/cogent/6A5Lb/

I could just use a background image for the percentage text but prefer all CSS.

thanks!

Comment: [This tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/) may help you.

Comment: you were very close http://jsfiddle.net/6A5Lb/95/ See first shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I actually figured it out with very little markup/css.

http://jsfiddle.net/o22b4uyz/2/

Markup

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='concave'><span class="percent">20%</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    background:blue;
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
} 
div.concave {
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50px;
left:-3px;
    }
span.percent {
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
```